# Deserializar Json sin tags

Tags: c#, json, vb

Tengo una respuesta de una API de la siguiente manera

```
[['exchange','UST',19788.6529257,0,19788.6529257,'Exchange 2.0 UST for USD @ 11.696',{reason: 'TRADE',order_id: 1189740779,order_id_oppo: 1189785673,trade_price: '11.696',trade_amount: '-2.0',order_cid: 1598516362757,order_gid: 1598516362629}],['exchange','BTC',0.1098938,0,0.1098938,'Trading fees for 0.0005 BTC (BTCUSD) @ 12000.0 on BFX (0.2%)',null],['exchange','USD',3848.93677654,0,3848.93677654,null,null],['exchange','SAN',19.76,0,19.76,null,null]]
```

Como se puede deserializar, ya que no existen tags que identifique cada valor, lo unico que se sabe es que la primera posición es el valor de tipo de billetera, la segunda posición es el tipo de moneda, igual con las otras posiciones se sabe que valor es.

Estoy programando en VB pero también lo puedo hacer en C#

Comment: Podrías incluir el código que has intentado?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Para empezar, eso no es un json... es una respuesta de algun tipo... Que intentaste?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo es una colección que tiene otras colecciones dentro, puedes hacer esto, este ejemplo es usando c#

```
 var json = "[['exchange','UST',19788.6529257,0,19788.6529257,'Exchange 2.0 UST for USD @ 11.696',{reason: 'TRADE',order_id: 1189740779,order_id_oppo: 1189785673,trade_price: '11.696',trade_amount: '-2.0',order_cid: 1598516362757,order_gid: 1598516362629}],['exchange','BTC',0.1098938,0,0.1098938,'Trading fees for 0.0005 BTC (BTCUSD) @ 12000.0 on BFX (0.2%)',null],['exchange','USD',3848.93677654,0,3848.93677654,null,null],['exchange','SAN',19.76,0,19.76,null,null]]";
var jsonDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<object>>>(json);
```

ahora mucho cuidado esto es válido si sabes que hay en cada posición, por ejemplo en el json que puso de ejemplo no todas las colecciones tienen la misma cantidad de elementos ni todos tienen valores tiene algunos con valor *null* y la primera colleción tiene un objeto al final que no tienen todos, Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar esta [pagina](https://json2csharp.com/) te sirve para que pueda convertir cualquier json a objeto ya manejado con objeto puedes deserializar de forma comoda.

Este fue el resultado que me dio la pagina cuando procese el json.

```
  public class Root
    {
        public List<List<object>> MyArray { get; set; }
    }
```

Debes utilizar NewtonSoft para deserealizar.

```
 Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
```